# Execute Azure Automation Runbooks Across Tenants

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am able to execute Runbooks within my Azure tenant/subscription, but would like to use a single Azure Automation Account in my tenant to execute Runbooks against other tenants and their subscriptions.

I have found this article for running against multiple subscriptions, but is it possible to have a centralized Azure Automation Account in one tenant that can connect and execute against other tenants and their subscriptions?

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/knightly/2017/05/26/using-azure-automation-with-multiple-subscriptions/

Comment: I don't see any reason why not, the only problem - auth.

Comment: Agreed. Any ideas of how to overcome this obstacle while using Resource Manager (not Classic)

Comment: well, grant permissions to the same service principal across tenants or use different service principals to talk to different tenants

Comment: @Kode I suggest you could use Azure AD account to login your subscription. You could check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, if your account is a Auzre AD account, it is possible. Also, your account is Microsoft account, you also could create a Azure AD account. More information about how to create a new Azure AD user please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-aduser-account#create-a-new-azure-active-directory-user).

You could create a credential and store your account and password in it.[image]

You can retrieve the credential in a runbook using the [`Get-AutomationPSCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-credentials) activity and then use it with `Add-AzureRmAccount` to connect to your Azure subscription. The following commands work for me.

```
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential –Name "shuitest"
Add-AzureRmAccount –Credential $cred
Select-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "Your Subscription Name"
```

More information about this, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-aduser-account#create-a-new-azure-active-directory-user).

If you want to login multiple tenants in one runbook, you need to sign in separately and execute your PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I will test this, and if all goes well, experiment with building an Array of Creds and Subscriptions to execute against multiple tenant

Comment: If my answer is helpful, don't forget to accept it.Thanks.

Comment: @Kode  Microsoft accounts(such as hotmail.com outloot.com) don't support non-interactive login. It means you should use AD account to login your subscription in runbook.

Answer (score 1):

So i stumbled upon this article which offers a guidance how to do what you want:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/knightly/2017/05/26/using-azure-automation-with-multiple-subscriptions/

basically what I said, get appId and grant it permissions to perform actions on other subs

Comment: It's going to be deprecated. Do we have any solution using Managed Identity

Comment: managed identity cannot work across tenant (i might be mistaken here), so this ask doesnt make sense. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26237

Comment: What about across subscription?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue today, specifically how to authenticate cross-tenant. I solved the authentication part of it by having an Azure Automation Account in both of my tenants, both with a RunAs Account.
By default these will be called `AzureRunAsConnection`

Tenant01 is my main Tenant that holds the Automation Account that does all the work.
Tenant02 is "passive".

- Use [this script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/126252/azure-automation-account-certificate.html) to export the certificate of Tenant02
- import the certificate into Tenant01
- in Tenant01 add an additional RunAs connection (e.g."AzureRunAsConnection02") and enter the ApplicationId, TenantId, CertificateThumbprint, SubscriptionId of the RunAs account from Tenant02

with identical RunAs accounts and certificates in both tenants you should now be able to switch between your Tenants in your runbook with:

```
Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection02
etc...
```